# How to get a screensaver at the Windows 7 login screen?

Tags: windows-7, login, screensaver

I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit. Since a couple of weeks, I no longer have a screensaver on the Windows login screen. If a user logs and then lock his session, the screensaver will start eventually but if no user are logged the login screen will never start the screensaver.

Anyone know how to set a screensaver there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if these steps will work if someone isn't logged on though!

> To enable the screensaver, first
>   choose the screensaver you want.  Look
>   in C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32 for files with
>   the .SCR extension - typically there
>   are the following (at least on my
>   Enterprise Installation)...
>
> - SSTEXT3D - 3D Text
> - BUBBLES.SCR - Bubbles
> - MYSTIFY.SCR - Mystify
> - PHOTOSCREENSAVER.SCR - Photos
> - RIBBONS.SCR - Ribbons
>
> One of the things to be aware of is
>   that you don't appear to have Direct3D
>   support at the logon screen so the
>   builtin screensavers above won't work.
>   Unless you have another file you might
>   want to grab the LOGON.SCR file from
>   an earlier operating system.
>
> Once you have your screensaver (in my
>   case LOGON.SCR), open your registry
>   editor and navigate to the following
>   key -
>
> ```
> HKEY_USERS \ .Default \ Control Panel \ Desktop
> ```
>
> [image]
>
> Below this key create the following
>   REG_SZ values...
>
> ```
> SCRNSAVE.EXE = C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\LOGON.SCR
> ScreenSaveActive = 1
> ScreenSaveIsSecure = 0
> ScreenSaveTimeOut = 60 (or whatever timeout you want in seconds)
> ```
>
> That's it - you'll have your
>   screensaver at the logon screen then.

Comment: This worked for me. Used logon.scr from Vista Ultimate and copied it to 7 Ultimate.

Comment: When you make a post to help, be careful! Wrong REG_SV Values. It's `ScreenSaveIsSecure` and not `ScreenSaverIsSecure`. It's `ScreenSaveIsSecure = 0` and not `1`.

Comment: Your hyperlink "these steps will work" does not lead to Article given in reference...

Comment: For Windows 7, logon.scr was renamed to scrnsaver.scr - so just use that as it does not require Direct3D.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, for Windows 7/Server 2008, if you compare the registry values in the same relative key location under YOUR hive, it is ScreensaveRIsSecure.   You may find yours to be 0 but references in other posts indicate it should be 1

Answer (score 0):

Look at this: [ScreenSaverIsSecure](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc959646.aspx)

`0`: The check box is cleared. The screen saver is not password-protected.

`1`: The check box is selected. The screen saver is password-protected.